# Associating a Function to Fire on session_start()?

Tags: php, session, constants

I've searched the web but haven't been able to find a solution to the following challenge:

I'd like to somehow associate a function that executes when `session_start` is called independent of the page `session_start` is called in. The function is intended to restore constants I've stored in `$_SESSION` using `get_defined_constants()` so that they're available again to any PHP page.

This seems so straightforward to me but I'm pretty sure the PHP Session extension doesn't support the registration of user-defined events. I was wondering if anyone might have insight into this issue so I can either figure out the solution or stop trying.

Ideally, I'd like to just register the function at run-time like so:

```
$constants = get_defined_constants();

$_SESSION["constants"] = $constants["user"];

function event_handler () {
    foreach ($_SESSION["constants"] as $key => $value) {
        define($key, $value);
    }
}

register_handler("session_start", "event_handler");
```

So in any webpage, I could just go:

```
session_start();
```

and all my constants would be available again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first question, since `$_SESSION` is a super-global variable, why would you need/want to extract them as constants (since they are available everywhere anyway)?

Comment: Not sure I understand - basically I want my user-defined constants (set on page 1) to be restored and used in page 2 when it is called automatically. I don't want to start referring to them in the $_SESSION array - I want to use them as constants (so both pages access the same information in the same way - no constants on page 1 and $_SESSION["constants] on page 2).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [session_set_save_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Although the functionality isn't as granular as you desire, it does fit the bill.

Comment: I thought about this but couldn't see how you append the sesson_start routine. I don't want to overwrite it and setup my own handlers (ie: not interested in changing the way storage is implemented) - I just wanted to tack on some extra code so to speak. Could you point me to an example of how I can use session_set_save_handler to do this without affecting how storage is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Besides of using your own session handle, you could also use a class to store the constants in, store that object in the session and use the [magic method `__wakeup`](http://php.net/language.oop5.magic) to write the constants when the constants object is rebuild on `session_start`.